# decode utf8 to big5

Tags: python, utf-8, big5

every one,I am trying to send sms by python, I can send it,but I need to send in Chinese, which is big5,I have to decode utf8 to big5,here is my sms python code

> trydecode.py

```
import urllib
import urllib2


def sendsms(phonenumber,textcontent):
    textcontent.decode('utf8').encode('big5')
    url = "https://url?username=myname&password=mypassword&dstaddr="+phonenumber+"&smbody="+textcontent
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

this code(python2.7) I can send sms in English but in Chinese (big5) got problem,how can I fix it? thank you

Comment: Chinese isn't BIG5; UTF-8 can also express Chinese just fine. What matters is what encoding the endpoint you're sending the data to expects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to save it to change the variable.

`textcontent = textcontent.decode('utf8').encode('big5')`

Comment: I will,stackoverflow said after 10 minutes